# Contextual Natural Language Resources, Where Do I Start?

Tags: .net, nlp

Where can i find some .Net or conceptual resources to start working with Natural Language where I can pull context and subjects from text. I wish not to work with word frequency algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find resources in part of speech tagging (a natural language processing task) look at this:

- [Natural Language Toolkit](http://nltk.sourceforge.net/index.php/Book)
- [PoS tagger in perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-Tagger/Tagger.pm)
- [SVM Tool](http://www.lsi.upc.es/~nlp/SVMTool/)
- [NLP Group at Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For English, there are the [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) files, are these the kind of resources you are looking for?

Comment: Great resource, I'm also looking for research papers or real world examples i can learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Hank's tag change leads to [a list of parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88984/your-favorite-natural-language-parser) and to [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332/whats-a-good-natural-language-library-to-use-for-paraphrasing)

Comment: Are there any .Net resources ?

Comment: I'm afraid that you won't find many .NET resources for NLP. C# isn't very strong in academia.

Answer (score 0):

Alex. S by speech you mean vocal processing or text processing? I'm looking for text processing resources at the moment. i have downloaded the book and will be going through it.