# Django DISTINCT match pattern with tolerance

Tags: python, django

See this older [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366448/is-there-a-way-to-filter-a-django-queryset-based-on-string-similarity-a-la-pyth)

I was wondering if there are any new features available (preferably native Django) that could find DISTINCT entries in my `Item` Model with a certain tolerance.

A simple example; I have these 5 Item-names:

- Item1 Linen Shirt
- Item2 Linen Shirt
- ItemB Linen Shirt1
- Item Linen Skirt
- ItemC Linen Skirt2

I would do something like:

```
item_set = Item.objects.distinct_special(name, tolerance = 95)
```

.. where the first value would be the field to search and the second value the tolerance as a percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in pure Python with difflib.

```
values = """Item1 Linen Shirt
Item2 Linen Shirt
ItemB Linen Shirt1
Item Linen Skirt
ItemC Linen Skirt2"""

data = values.split('\n')

print(difflib.get_close_matches(data[0], data))
```

Check the documentation for [get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) for additional parameters like tolerance.

Comment: Thank you Matthias. I hope searching getting all Names and ID's first of millions of records, it will not impact the performance too much :P

Comment: Getting all the data from the database server to the client will have an impact on performance, but at least the task can be done. Good luck.