# Function that returns affinity between texts?

Tags: algorithm, text, full-text-search, relevance

consider I have a

```
string1 = "hello hi goodmorning evening [...]"
```

and I have some minor keywords

```
compare1 = "hello evening"
compare2 = "hello hi"
```

I need a function that returns the affinity between the text and keywords. Example:

```
function(string1,compare1);  // returns: 4
function(string1,compare2);  // returns: 5 (more relevant)
```

Please note 5 and 4 are just for example.

You could say - write a function that counts occurrences - but for this example this would not work because both got 2 occurrences, but compare1 is less relevant because "hello evening" isn't exactly found in string1 (the 2 words hello and evening are more distant than hello hi)

are there any known-algorithm to do this?

ADD1:

algos like Edit Distance in this case would NOT work. 
Because string1 is a complete text (like 300-400 words) and the comparing strings are max 4-5 word.

Comment: Are you looking for simple string edit-distance comparison or full on semantic equivalence?  e.g. is cat more similar to cart or feline?

Comment: none of both.. I would need something like count occurences+give weight based on the words distances (as i explained previos: string1 is an article with 300-400words and the comparing strings are just 3-4 words)

Comment: Do your keywords always come in pairs? What's more important, having more matching words or better proximity?

Comment: 1. not always in pairs, the comparing string can be up to 5-6 words
2. 50%-50%

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A Dynamic Programing Algorithm

It seems what you are looking for is very similar to what the [**Smith–Waterman algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) does.

From Wikipedia:

> The algorithm was first proposed by Temple F. Smith and Michael S. Waterman in 1981.  Like the [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm) algorithm, of which it is a variation, Smith-Waterman is a [dynamic programming algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). As such, it has the desirable property that it is guaranteed to find the optimal local alignment with respect to the scoring system being used (which includes the substitution matrix and the gap-scoring  scheme).

Let's see a practical example, so you can evaluate its usefulness.

Suppose we have a text:

```
text = "We the people of the United States, in order to form a more 
perfect union, establish justice, insure domestic tranquility, 
provide for the common defense, 

  promote the general welfare, 

  and secure the blessings of liberty to ourselves and our posterity, 
do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of 
America.";
```

I isolated the segment we are going to match, just for your easy of reading.

We will compare the affinity (or similarity) with a list of strings:

```
list = {
   "the general welfare",
   "my personal welfare",
   "general utopian welfare",
   "the general",
   "promote welfare",
   "stackoverflow rulez"
   };
```

I have the algorithm already implemented, so I'll calculate the similarity and normalize the results:

```
sw = SmithWatermanSimilarity[ text, #] & /@ list;
swN = (sw - Min[sw])/(Max[sw] - Min[sw])
```

Then we Plot the results:

[image]

I think it's very similar to your expected result.

HTH!

**Some implementations (w/source code)**

- [Smith-Waterman CUDA Source Code
  (GSW)](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~rcl/gsw.html)
- [The S-M algorithm explained
  (presentation)](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~lily/pres2/sld012.htm)
- [An interactive step-by-step demo
  applet](http://baba.sourceforge.net/)
- [Java Source code](http://jaligner.sourceforge.net/)
- [Python source code](http://narnia.cs.ttu.edu/drupal/node/104)

Comment: This might be the solution! But why ur function is called "SmithWatermanSimilarity" and not just "SmithWaterman": I mean do you have some customization? Anyway do you have a pseudocode description for this? So I can translate in my language (php)

Comment: @yes123 At the end of my answer there are a few links (you may find a lot) including three implementations and two "educative" resources. I can't provide mine because it isn't open source.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe I will try the cuda or java implementation to see if it fits my needs (like your solution). If I will translate to php I will post a link here, thanks

Comment: I am testing some java implementations. It seems those implementations consider chars and not the entry words. That's a big problem for me

Comment: @yes123 it works well with words too, try it. It is designed to match DNA sequences that are like words

Comment: @yes123 Once you do some testing, please return and leave some comments. I'm very interested on knowing how the algorithm represent your specific requirements!

Comment: the implementations i am using in php gives me the same score of "1" to "the general welfare" and "the general", if u want see the php code i will post the link..

Comment: @yes123 So it is very badly broken, because that kind of alignment is the most basic thing the algorithm do right. You can check at http://baba.sourceforge.net/ what should be the intermediate results and how increasing the text match length increases the score.

Comment: here there is the code: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#I08I-vVKhsw/trunk/biostor/swa.php too bad it's not that great =/

Comment: @yes123 The code is not working properly. It works well only for perfect alignment. :(

Comment: i don't get why such an important algos for search (score based on proximity) isn't that known, especially for php that works with website/searches =/

Comment: @yes123 You may try to find the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm, but this one is much better for your purpose. I'm not savvy in PHP, so can't help much with that. Sorry.

Comment: nothing neither for needleman. The problem here is that those 2 algos are used in Bioinformatics... that's why in PHP are completly unknown

Comment: well i have write a function on my own to do this. Results are very close to your results. I would like to share and discuss my solution with you, can we talk privately  (email,chat,msn,fb) ? this little comment space here hurts me rly.

Comment: @yes123 It's preferred that the communication happens on Stack Overflow so that the solution to your problem can be shared by the community. That's what we're here for, to make the programming world a better place by sharing our knowledge publicly.

Comment: @george i am perfectly agree. but this little space is absoluty awful to discuss such things. thus stackoverflow (by rules) is a Q&A website only, not a discussion board :) (and that why the comments here are so limited)

Comment: @belisarius :( are you there? :(

Comment: @yes123 yes, I'm here. Check if you can establish a private chat room in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and invite me

Comment: @belisarius can't do it with chat :( Anyway I have created a link for you. Go [here](http://codepad.org/tbsEYTw0) you can test my algo. As you can see (at the bottom of the codepad page) "the general welfare" got the highest score of 8 points. If you have any suggestions tell me. Please note I have not used any of well known algo.. I just wrote it myself

Comment: @yes123 If your algorithm gives you consistent results go ahead! It's not of course the SW algo, and seems to favor too little for longer matches.

Comment: @belisarius yes I am currently using it with good results. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @belisarius [These implementations](https://github.com/alevchuk/pairwise-alignment-in-python) of the Smith–Waterman and Needleman-Wunsch algorithms are much cleaner starting point Python implementations than the one you link to for S-W in your post.

Comment: @dtanders Thanks! Feel free to edit my answer if you think they are better than those I found

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into creating N-grams out of your input data and then matching on the N-grams. I have a solution where I regard each n-gram as a dimension in a vector space (which becomes a space of 4000 dimensions in my case) and then affinity is the cosine of the angle between two vectors (the dot-product is involved here).

The hard part is to come up with a metric defining the affinity in a way you want.

An alternative is to look at a sliding window and score based on how many words in your compare_x data is in the window. The final score is the sum.

Comment: Hm even if it's interesting i dont think u can use this sliding window because you cant choose a winodws size that alyawys works imo. I was thinking something more like this: first counts only occorunces then remove some points based on how much chars there are between found keys. But i cannot belive there isnt already a known algo for this job... Its so important in search-related stuff. Regsrding other solution using ngrams i dont have a clear idea on how to make it

Comment: There is no clear-cut solution because different metrics are wanted for different purposes.

Comment: why you say that? I am pretty sure someone else already wrote algos for this (i don't think it would be too hard) I found some mathematics solution to the problem here: http://domino.mpi-inf.mpg.de/intranet/ag5/ag5publ.nsf/448742fce85ecfa580255f0d006b34c7/10cbd344ae4d0108c12576fe00388df3/$FILE/Akkuzhyna_master.pdf At page 31 there is a solution "For every term t of a query q= {t1, . . . , tn},  we compute an accumulator acc that contains 
proximity score of t within the current element e:"

Answer (score 2):

`py-editdist` will give you the [Levenshtein edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings, which is one metric that might be helpful.

See:  http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-editdist/

The code example from that page:

```
import editdist

# Calculate the edit distance between two strings
d = editdist.distance("abc", "bcdef")
```

Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a pretty good and complete answer to this question here 
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=337832

Sorry its on google answers!

Comment: Half of the link on that page don't work. And the other half don't speak at all about proximity

Comment: If you mean proximity, as in meaning,

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a list of metrics to calculate distance between strings, and an opensource java library that just do that.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric
In particular, take a look at the Smith–Waterman algorithm, keeping in mind that what they call "Alphabet" can be composed by what we call Strings : so, given the alphabet

```
{A = "hello", B = "hi",C = "goodmorning",D = "evening"}
```

and called d the distance, your function tries to calculate

```
d(ABCD,AB) vs d(ABCD,AC)
```

Comment: HM, I read Smith–Waterman works great on characters.. I need this algo for text =/

Comment: As pointed out before, think at each word as a  consant char, and you should be done

Comment: Hm so I should build my Alphabet based on my text and my comparing string and give them to the algos? I am not sure it can work because algos supports stuff like "insertion"/"deletion" that work for chars

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can count the occurrences of pieces of the comparing text, ie:

"a-b-c" -> "a" , "b" , "c" , "a-b" ," b-c" , "a-b-c"  (possible "a-c", if you wanted that)

And then count occurrences of each of those, and sum them, possibly with a weight of (length of string) / (length of whole string).

Then you just need a way to produce those pieces, and run a check for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

While the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) as it stands may not suit your purposes, a modification of it might: Try implementing it by storing the insertions, deletions, and substitutions separately.

The distance will then be the sum of the following:

- All Substutions
- The number of spaces minus one in each set of consecutive insertions/deletions:

  - (In your case: " hi goodmorning " only counts as two edits, and ' [...] ' counts as one.)

You'd have to test this, of course, but if it doesn't work well try simply using the sum of consecutive insertions/deletions (so, " hi good morning " is only 1 edit).

**EDIT**

P.S.: this assumes a relatively major change to how Levenshtein works, you'd want to 'align' your data first (finding out where there's significant (more than two characters) overlap and inserting 'null' characters that would count as insertions).

Also, this is just an untested idea, so any ideas for improvements are welcome.