# Compare similarity between two string with PHP

Tags: php, similarity

Hey guys :) I want to ask for some solution. Now, I have dictionary **words.txt**, here some example:

```
happy
laugh
sad
```

And I have the **slang string**:

```
hppy
```

I want to **search & match** that slang string **to my dictionary** wich means it will return "happy" because those string **refer to "happy"** in **dictionary**.

Recently I've been using **similar_text()** but doesn't confident about its validity. Can you guys recommend **better solution** for my problem? Thank you :)

And here i put my codes:

```
function searchwords($tweet){
//echo $tweet;
$find       = false;
$handle     = @fopen("words.txt", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer         = fgets($handle);
        similar_text(trim($tweet),trim($buffer),$percent);
        if ($percent == 100){ // this exact match
            $find = true;
        }else if ($percent >= 90){ //there is the possibility of errors
            $find = true;
        }

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
  if ($find == true){
    unset($tweet);
  }else{
    return $tweet;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236357/4852737)

> I've found that to calculate a similarity percentage between strings,
>   the [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Jaro Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) algorithms work well for
>   spelling mistakes and small changes between strings, while the [Smith
>   Waterman Gotoh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) algorithm works well for strings where significant
>   chunks of the text would be the same but with "noise" around the
>   edges. [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235657/4852737) shows more detail on
>   this.

I included the php examples of using each of these three examples to return a similarity percentage between two strings:

### [Levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

```
echo levenshtein("LEGENDARY","BARNEY STINSON");
```

### [Jaro Winkler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236260/4852737)

```
class StringCompareJaroWinkler 
{
    public function compare($str1, $str2)
    {
        return $this->JaroWinkler($str1, $str2, $PREFIXSCALE = 0.1 );
    }

    private function getCommonCharacters( $string1, $string2, $allowedDistance ){

      $str1_len = mb_strlen($string1);
      $str2_len = mb_strlen($string2);
      $temp_string2 = $string2;

      $commonCharacters='';
      for( $i=0; $i < $str1_len; $i++){

        $noMatch = True;
        // compare if char does match inside given allowedDistance
        // and if it does add it to commonCharacters
        for( $j= max( 0, $i-$allowedDistance ); $noMatch && $j < min( $i + $allowedDistance + 1, $str2_len ); $j++){
          if( $temp_string2[$j] == $string1[$i] ){
            $noMatch = False;
        $commonCharacters .= $string1[$i];
        $temp_string2[$j] = '';
          }
        }
      }
      return $commonCharacters;
    }

    private function Jaro( $string1, $string2 ){

      $str1_len = mb_strlen( $string1 );
      $str2_len = mb_strlen( $string2 );

      // theoretical distance
      $distance = (int) floor(min( $str1_len, $str2_len ) / 2.0); 

      // get common characters
      $commons1 = $this->getCommonCharacters( $string1, $string2, $distance );
      $commons2 = $this->getCommonCharacters( $string2, $string1, $distance );

      if( ($commons1_len = mb_strlen( $commons1 )) == 0) return 0;
      if( ($commons2_len = mb_strlen( $commons2 )) == 0) return 0;
      // calculate transpositions
      $transpositions = 0;
      $upperBound = min( $commons1_len, $commons2_len );
      for( $i = 0; $i < $upperBound; $i++){
        if( $commons1[$i] != $commons2[$i] ) $transpositions++;
      }
      $transpositions /= 2.0;
      // return the Jaro distance
      return ($commons1_len/($str1_len) + $commons2_len/($str2_len) + ($commons1_len - $transpositions)/($commons1_len)) / 3.0;

    }

    private function getPrefixLength( $string1, $string2, $MINPREFIXLENGTH = 4 ){

      $n = min( array( $MINPREFIXLENGTH, mb_strlen($string1), mb_strlen($string2) ) );

      for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        if( $string1[$i] != $string2[$i] ){
          // return index of first occurrence of different characters 
          return $i;
        }
      }
      // first n characters are the same   
      return $n;
    }

    private function JaroWinkler($string1, $string2, $PREFIXSCALE = 0.1 ){

      $JaroDistance = $this->Jaro( $string1, $string2 );
      $prefixLength = $this->getPrefixLength( $string1, $string2 );
      return $JaroDistance + $prefixLength * $PREFIXSCALE * (1.0 - $JaroDistance);
    }
}

$jw = new StringCompareJaroWinkler();
echo $jw->compare("LEGENDARY","BARNEY STINSON");
```

### [Smith Waterman Gotoh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235828/4852737)

```
class SmithWatermanGotoh 
{
    private $gapValue;
    private $substitution;

    /**
     * Constructs a new Smith Waterman metric.
     * 
     * @param gapValue
     *            a non-positive gap penalty
     * @param substitution
     *            a substitution function
     */
    public function __construct($gapValue=-0.5, 
                $substitution=null) 
    {
        if($gapValue > 0.0) throw new Exception("gapValue must be <= 0");
        //if(empty($substitution)) throw new Exception("substitution is required");
        if (empty($substitution)) $this->substitution = new SmithWatermanMatchMismatch(1.0, -2.0);
        else $this->substitution = $substitution;
        $this->gapValue = $gapValue;
    }

    public function compare($a, $b) 
    {
        if (empty($a) && empty($b)) {
            return 1.0;
        }

        if (empty($a) || empty($b)) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        $maxDistance = min(mb_strlen($a), mb_strlen($b))
                * max($this->substitution->max(), $this->gapValue);
        return $this->smithWatermanGotoh($a, $b) / $maxDistance;
    }

    private function smithWatermanGotoh($s, $t) 
    {   
        $v0 = [];
        $v1 = [];
        $t_len = mb_strlen($t);
        $max = $v0[0] = max(0, $this->gapValue, $this->substitution->compare($s, 0, $t, 0));

        for ($j = 1; $j < $t_len; $j++) {
            $v0[$j] = max(0, $v0[$j - 1] + $this->gapValue,
                    $this->substitution->compare($s, 0, $t, $j));

            $max = max($max, $v0[$j]);
        }

        // Find max
        for ($i = 1; $i < mb_strlen($s); $i++) {
            $v1[0] = max(0, $v0[0] + $this->gapValue, $this->substitution->compare($s, $i, $t, 0));

            $max = max($max, $v1[0]);

            for ($j = 1; $j < $t_len; $j++) {
                $v1[$j] = max(0, $v0[$j] + $this->gapValue, $v1[$j - 1] + $this->gapValue,
                        $v0[$j - 1] + $this->substitution->compare($s, $i, $t, $j));

                $max = max($max, $v1[$j]);
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < $t_len; $j++) {
                $v0[$j] = $v1[$j];
            }
        }

        return $max;
    }
}

class SmithWatermanMatchMismatch
{
    private $matchValue;
    private $mismatchValue;

    /**
     * Constructs a new match-mismatch substitution function. When two
     * characters are equal a score of <code>matchValue</code> is assigned. In
     * case of a mismatch a score of <code>mismatchValue</code>. The
     * <code>matchValue</code> must be strictly greater then
     * <code>mismatchValue</code>
     * 
     * @param matchValue
     *            value when characters are equal
     * @param mismatchValue
     *            value when characters are not equal
     */
    public function __construct($matchValue, $mismatchValue) {
        if($matchValue <= $mismatchValue) throw new Exception("matchValue must be > matchValue");

        $this->matchValue = $matchValue;
        $this->mismatchValue = $mismatchValue;
    }

    public function compare($a, $aIndex, $b, $bIndex) {
        return ($a[$aIndex] === $b[$bIndex] ? $this->matchValue
                : $this->mismatchValue);
    }

    public function max() {
        return $this->matchValue;
    }

    public function min() {
        return $this->mismatchValue;
    }
}

$o = new SmithWatermanGotoh();
echo $o->compare("LEGENDARY","BARNEY STINSON");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. PHP no longer supports assigning an empty string to a string offset. What was the intended behavior of:      $temp_string2[$j] = '';

Comment: Add an is_array() check around that line. Sometimes it's a string, sometimes it's an array.

Comment: `if ( is_array($temp_string2)) { $temp_string2[$j] = ''; }`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it'll serve your purpose. But there are some things to keep in mind while working with `similar_text()`.

1. matching percentage can differ depending on the  order of parameters. ie: `similar_text($a, $b, $percent)` and `similar_text($b, $a, $percent)` here in both cases $percent may not be same.
2. Note that this function is case sensitive: so while passing $a and $b pass both either in uppercase or lowercase.

for more info check [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)