# What is a good strategy to group similar words?

Tags: python, algorithm, redis

Say I have a list of movie names with misspellings and small variations like this -

```
 "Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl"
 "Pirates of the carribean"
 "Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest"
 "Pirates of the Caribbean trilogy"
 "Pirates of the Caribbean"
 "Pirates Of The Carribean"
```

How do I group or find such sets of words, preferably using python and/or redis?

Comment: what do you want to get as a result ? you want to look for all these variations in a whole string ?

Comment: I would like to group these into a combined object and perform a check when adding to the database.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at "fuzzy matching". Some great tools in the thread below that calculates similarities between strings.

I'm especially fond of the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) module

```
>>> get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])
['apple', 'ape']
>>> import keyword
>>> get_close_matches('wheel', keyword.kwlist)
['while']
>>> get_close_matches('apple', keyword.kwlist)
[]
>>> get_close_matches('accept', keyword.kwlist)
['except']
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison

Comment: the linked question seems to be deleted.

Comment: so it seems. When you reach a certain level of points you can still however see the deleted questions so I leve the link just as it is

Comment: @FredrikPihl could you please post the definition for `get_close_matches` here (or edit it in to the answer) for us unworthy low-reputation peasants?

Comment: It looks like I asked too soon - it's just a method as part of difflib: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

Answer (score 5):

You might notice that similar strings have large common substring, for example:

> "Bla bla bLa" and "Bla bla bRa" => common substring is "Bla bla ba" (notice the third word)

To find common substring you may use dynamic programming algorithm. One of algorithms variations is **Levenshtein distance** (distance between most similar strings is very small, and between more different strings distance is bigger) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.

Also for quick performance you may try to adapt **Soundex algorithm** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex.

So after calculating distance between all your strings, you have to clusterize them. The most simple way is **k-means** (but it needs you to define number of clusters). If you actually don't know number of clusters, you have to use hierarchical clustering. *Note that number of clusters in your situation is **number of different movies titles + 1**(for totally bad spelled strings).*

Comment: your so called substring "Bla bla ba" is not a substring in the conventional definition, since "ba" is in neither of your strings. I'd call it a "gapped substring". From the common gapped substring you can get the longest ungapped substring and thus the longest common substring.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to use k-means or hierarchical clustering on distances, as finding distance between words results in 2D array of distances of pairs of phrases ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is in fact two distinct problems.

The first is spell correction. You can have one in Python here

http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

The second is more functional. Here is what I'd do after the spell correction. I would make a relation function.

related( sentence1, sentence2 ) if and only if sentence1 and sentence2 have rare common words. By rare, I mean words different than (The, what, is, etc...). You can take a look at the TF/IDF system to determine if two document are related using their words. Just googling a bit I found this:

https://code.google.com/p/tfidf/

Answer (score 1):

To add another tip to Fredrik's answer, you could also get inspired from *search engines* like code, such as this one :

```
def dosearch(terms, searchtype, case, adddir, files = []):
    found = []
    if files != None:
        titlesrch = re.compile('>title<.*>/title<')
        for file in files:
            title = ""
            if not (file.lower().endswith("html") or file.lower().endswith("htm")):
                continue
            filecontents = open(BASE_DIR + adddir + file, 'r').read()
            titletmp = titlesrch.search(filecontents)
            if titletmp != None:
                title = filecontents.strip()[titletmp.start() + 7:titletmp.end() - 8]
            filecontents = remove_tags(filecontents)
            filecontents = filecontents.lstrip()
            filecontents = filecontents.rstrip()
            if dofind(filecontents, case, searchtype, terms) > 0:
                found.append(title)
                found.append(file)
    return found
```

**Source** and more information: http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/search-engine-python/

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to pre-process all the strings before you compare them: convert all to lowercase, standardize whitespace (eg, replace any whitespace with single spaces). If punctuation is not important to your end goal, you can remove all punctuation characters as well.

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is commonly-used to determine similarity of a string, this should help you group strings which differ by small spelling errors.

Comment: [here](https://python.gotrained.com/nltk-edit-distance-jaccard-distance/#Edit_Distance) is a link that provides a good explanation of what this answer is trying to talk about.