# Python non strict search text in string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to see if a string contains certain text and if so do something, i have been using python's `in` operator, but i realized its too strict basically i have the following code

Usually this would return `True`

```
dynamic = "v23434"
filename = "v23434.jpg"

if dynamic in filename: return True
```

however, if i have

```
dynamic = "v23434-"
filename = "v23434.jpg"
```

then it returns False, due to the dash at the end of `dynamic`, so my question is, is there a way to check if the string filename has the string `dynamic`, but in a way that it doesn't have to be a perfect match, a few characters is enough.

*EDIT*

By a few characters, i mean a substring made up of the first 3 characters in dynamic, so if i have

```
dynamic = "v23434-"
filename = "testingv23434.jpg"
```

then it should match, because the substring `"v23"` is found inside `filename`

Comment: Well, how do you define "a few characters"? How do you define an imperfect match? Do you need the _first_ few (and how many?) characters of `dynamic` to be found in `filename`, or are you looking for _any_ substring of `dynamic` that occurs in `filename`? Possibly with some minimum length? There are algorithms to solve all these problems, but you have to be specific about what your requirements are.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/682367/566644) question.

Comment: you could use stuff like Levenshtein distance

Comment: @david i edited the question to be more specific, thank you for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test the first three characters in your search term, then use

```
def test(dynamic, filename):
    return dynamic[:3] in filename
```

Comment: @danihp: That's what he wanted. But thanks for the hint about the unnecessary `if`!

Answer (score 1):

Just slice off the first three characters of the one string:

```
if dynamic[:3] in filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code will help with your issue i you are looking for **at least 3 consecutive chars**:

```
>>> dynamic = "v23434-"
>>> filename = "testingv23434.jpg"
>>> any( s in filename for s in [ dynamic[i:i+3] for i in range( 0, len(dynamic)-2 ) ] )
True

>>> filename = "testingv334.jpg"
>>> any( s in filename for s in [ dynamic[i:i+3] for i in range( 0, len(dynamic)-2 ) ] )
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need edit distances: http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-editdist/