# Smart string search python (maybe) using whoosh

Tags: python, string, search, whoosh

I need to make a search method that is a little smarter than the find() in python. Something that could find similar words more like a search engine. I heard of Whoosh, installed it, but I couldn't even understand where to start from. Could someone either teach me some really basic whoosh string search methods or give me another option?

Comment: http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/quickstart.html

Comment: What kind of searches do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I have this file: http://pastebin.com/F28RXDvu and I want to let the user search for parts of the strings, or the same one with different case...

Comment: Not sure if this is a dupe or not, but you may find the following useful: [Good Python modules for fuzzy string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for fuzzy string matching?

If so you might be interested in checking out [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).

Comment: It worked well for many cases, but I'm still searching for some more automatic smart search.