# Python - Best Matching Search

Tags: python, search, match

I have a SiriServerCore setup that I'm programming to essentially automate functions for my media center. This media center has movies, tv shows, and music on it. Essentially the voice to text will receive something like *"Play The Final Episode by Asking Alexandria*". In a python list containing all my music's file locations, there is a file called *"Asking Alexandria - 2 - The Final Episode (Let's Change Channel).mp3"*. How would I go about having the text speech "best match" to the items in the list? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's more of a generic algorithm question rather than python. On top of the head you might want to build an index of all the words in the captions/titles you have in your collection, than use some kind of full text search engine (tons of them on the internet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your voice input will be transformed into a string you can simply iterate over the song list, look at first two or three words of the song title, compare each title with the input string and if some or most words of the song title are present in string representing your voice you can make a decision about the right song.This would be something like:

```
>>> a = "Play The Final Episode by Asking Alexandria" # voice input
>>> songList = ["Asking Alexandria - 2 - The Final Episode (Let's Change Channel).mp3",      "Angie", "Yesterday.mp3"]
>>> for songTitle in SongsList:
        songTitleWords = songTitle.split(" ")
        if " ".join(songTitleWords[:2]) in voiceInput: 
            # play the song
```

But this is more of a hunch rather then a perfect solution. I think that first words of a song title are usually most important. At the same time it is better to start from song title and match song title to voice input rather then the other way around because voice input can contain unnecessary elements, first three words of a voice input may be something like "please play me a song of the title". First words of song title are usually informative.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison), you might want to use this [library for fuzzy string comparisons](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/). It checks the similarity between two strings; you can use that to find the best match.

Comment: I doubt this lib would yield good results. `Play The Final Episode by Asking Alexandria` and `Asking Alexandria - 2 - The Final Episode` have huge Levenshtein distance, but, well, it's a perfect match actually.