# Python: How to find the position of the character that makes the levenshtein distance

Tags: python, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

I'm calculating the levenshtein distance for some strings. Only the one with a distance of 1 I want to analyze further. What I'm interested in, above all, is the position of the character that makes the distance. So for example;

```
('rodange', 'redange', 1)  # position 2
```

I can think of a couple of ways to get there but they seem not very handy (like looping through all characters and comparing them one by one). Something out there already?

Comment: isn't the cost of replace is 2 for levenshtein distance?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you mean with replace? And which cost?

Comment: as far as I remember, levenshtein distance is a sum of inserts deletes and replaces of characters, so you could change word1 into word2 in N steps. insert and delete costs 1 and update = insert + delete cost 2. So in your case difference betweed rodange and redange is not 1, but 2

Comment: take a look here - http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf. I could try to find solution for you, but it would be nice to know that I'll calucalate difference you need

Comment: No, it's the absolute distance, Have look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a better solution than what you already figured out. Either add code that returns the index of the first change to the levenshtein algorithm you are using. That should be a single line at the right place, and a modified return statement.

Or loop through it like you say, not too difficult either:

```
idx = next(i for (i, (a, b)) in enumerate(zip(w1, w2)) if a != b)
```

If you prefer it shorter:

```
from operator import eq
idx = map(eq, w1, w2).index(False)
```