# Percentage of how similar strings are in Python?

Tags: python, string, fuzzy-comparison

I don't know how to do a program that gives a percentage of how similar two strings of the same length are.

For example, for `abcd` and `abce` it should give 75%.

The order matters, I don't want that it gives me that `abcd` and `dcab` have a 100%.

I know that Levenshtein module does that, but I want a program that does it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Python modules for fuzzy string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Comment: Not a duplicate, please read carefully, in that thread they ask for a module, and I want a program that does it!

Comment: Well, asking for a complete program to be handed to you isn't really acceptable here. You need to demonstrate some understanding of the problem. So I suggested that as a pointer for your research.

Comment: Ok, I'll have that in mind when I ask again.
Thanks :)

Comment: Further, the Levenshtein module _is_ "a program", that you've already said does what you want. The top-voted answer at the question I've linked shows the function call you need to make.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, 'abcd', 'abce').ratio()
0.75
```

Read the docs for more.  You can read the description in the docs to figure out how to do it yourself, but you're going to end up coding *some* kind of alignment algorithm from scratch.

Comment: I believe by looking at his examples, he is actually looking for `longets common substring`

Comment: @Abhijit, yes, you said that in your answer ;-)  But I don't believe it.  The OP implied that the Levenshtein module does what he wants, but Levenshtein isn't longest common anything - it's "minimal edit distance", which isn't the same thing.  The `difflib` algorithm is akin to a longest common substring applied recursively.

Comment: But then, `SequenceMatcher(None, 'abcd', 'abce').ratio() = 0.25` and not 0 as shown in his example. So the question is confusing, and OP is not aware of what he actually wants :-)

Comment: I agree the question is unclear.  As my answer says, `SequenceMatcher(None, 'abcd', 'abce').ratio()` returns `0.75` (not `0.25`), and the OP said they wanted `75%`.  I don't see anything the OP said about any example returning `0`.  The only other I see is that they **don't** want `abcd` and `dcab` to return 100%.

Answer (score 2):

The word similar has varied context, but looking at your examples, I am definite, you are looking for the

```
Match% = 2* Longest_Common_Substring(a, b) / (len(a) + len(b)) * 100
```

Just google for Longest Common Substring and you are sure to find loads of Python Implementation.

One such [Python Implementation from Wikibook : Algorithm Implementation/Strings/Longest common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Python) is as follows

```
def longest_common_substring(s1, s2):
    m = [[0] * (1 + len(s2)) for i in xrange(1 + len(s1))]
    longest, x_longest = 0, 0
    for x in xrange(1, 1 + len(s1)):
        for y in xrange(1, 1 + len(s2)):
            if s1[x - 1] == s2[y - 1]:
                m[x][y] = m[x - 1][y - 1] + 1
                if m[x][y] > longest:
                    longest = m[x][y]
                    x_longest = x
            else:
                m[x][y] = 0
    return s1[x_longest - longest: x_longest]
```

wrapping it over with a similarity function, the result conforms to your expectation

```
>>> def similarity(s1, s2):
     return 2. * len(longest_common_substring(s1, s2)) / (len(s1) + len(s2)) * 100

>>> similarity("abcd","abce")
75.0
>>> similarity("abcd","dcba")
25.0
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach, but we can't use this for practical purpose whe nstring size is huge. It is very slow. Instead we can use SequenceMatcher's longest substring method to find substring, and use the wrapper around it as you have defined similarity() method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that s1 and s2 have the same length:

```
from numpy import mean
mean([s1[i]==s2[i] for i in xrange(len(s1))])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> a = list('abce')
>>> b = list('abcd')
>>> ( 100 - (sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b)) / float(len(a))) * 100 )
75.0
>>> a = list('abce')
>>> b = list('bdce')
>>> ( 100 - (sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b)) / float(len(a))) * 100 )
50.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has pseudocode for [Levenshtein_distance or Edit Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
It is a simple algorithm. Why don't you give it a try and ask specific question if you are stuck.