# Similarity score of two lists with strings

Tags: python, comparison, string-comparison, similarity, fuzzy-comparison

I have a list of strings as a query and a few hundrends of other lists of strings. I want to compare the query with every other list and extract a similarity score between them.

Example:

```
query = ["football", "basketball", "martial arts", "baseball"]

list1 = ["apple", "football", "basketball court"]

list2 = ["ball"]

list3 = ["martial-arts", "baseball", "banana", "food", "doctor"]
```

What I am doing now and I am not satisfied with the results is an absolute compare of them.

```
score = 0
for i in query:
   if i in list1:
      score += 1

score_of_list1 = score*100//len(list1)
```

I found a library that may help me [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy), but I was thinking if you have any other way to suggest.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with your solution. What sort of comparison do you want? Perhaps give an example of a result you'd accept and how it's better.

Comment: As I said, since it is an absolute comparison, I don' have high scores. So, I am looking for another sollution which will maybe increase the score.

Comment: What you mean is you want a way to compare the strings, not the lists. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but the final score will be between the lists. Just like the example in my question. I compare the strings and then I calculate a score between the lists in base of the string comparison results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to find similarity between strings, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison?rq=1) suggests [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) as a method of doing so.

There is a [solution](https://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/) ready, and it also exists in the [Natural Language Tool Kit](http://www.nltk.org/) library.

The **naive** integration would be (I use random merely to have a result. It doesn't make sense obviously):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
query = ["football", "basketball", "martial arts", "baseball"]
lists = [["apple", "football", "basketball court"], ["ball"], ["martial-arts", "baseball", "banana", "food", "doctor"]]
from random import random

def fake_levenshtein(word1, word2):
    return random()

def avg_list(l):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)

for l in lists:
    score = []
    for w1 in l:
        for w2 in query:
            score.append(fake_levenshtein(w1, w2))
    print avg_list(score)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for a while and if I do not have any other answers, I will choose yours!