# How to return the most similar word from a list of words?

Tags: python, regex, list, nltk, levenshtein-distance

How to create a function that returns the most similar word from a list of words, even if the word is not exactly the same?

The function should have two inputs: one for the word and the other for the list. The function should return the word that is most similar to the word.

```
lst = ['apple','app','banana store','pear','beer']

func('apple inc.',lst)
>>'apple'
func('banana',lst)
>>'banana store'
```

From doing some research, it seems that I have to use the concepts of Fuzzy String Matching, NLTK, and Levenshtein-distance, which I'm having a hard time trying to implement in creating a function like this.

I should also point out that by similar, I just mean the characters and I'm not concerned for the meaning of the word at all.

Comment: You should have some concrete heuristics. Currently, this question is too broad.

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by "similar". Consider the word `Bird`. Which of the words `Crow` and `Bard` are more similar to `Bird`? Depending on what your answer is, your approach will be different.

Comment: Thanks for asking. By similar, I mean only similarity in terms of the characters and not similarity in the meaning of the word. So Bird would be more similar to Bard than it is for Crow in my use-case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Python modules for fuzzy string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Comment: Isn't there a difflib in python's standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slow solution for debugging:

```
def func(word, lst):
  items = sorted((dist(word, w), w) for w in lst)
  # Print items here for debugging.
  if not items: 
    raise ValueError('List of words is empty.')
  return items[0][1]
```

Or, this is faster and uses less memory:

```
def func(word, lst):
  return min((dist(word, w), w) for w in lst)[1]
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison for implementing `dist`. One of the answers has a link to a Levenshtein-distance implementation.

Comment: Thanks - just to be clear, only need to import Levenshtein to use this?

Comment: You have to install it first, and then you can import it.