# Compare strings, allowing one character difference

Tags: python, string

I have been trying to implement tabular method for simplification of boolean expressions in python. For that I need to check whether two given strings differ at only one index
for example, the function should return the following for the following examples:

- `0011` and `0111` - true as the two differ only at position 1
- `0-001` and `0-101` - true as differ at only 2
- `0-011` and `0-101` - false as differ at 2,3

right now I am using the following function:

```
def match(s1,s2):

    l=[False,-1]##returns false when they cant be combined
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[:i]==s2[:i] and s1[i]!=s2[i] and s1[i+1:]==s2[i+1:]:
            l= [True,i]
            break
    return l
```

I want to implement it in a very fast manner (low complexity). Is there a way to do so in python?

Comment: Is "0011" equal to "011"? Or must the length be the same?

Comment: Do you mean 'at most'?

Comment: the two input strings have the same length

Comment: i mean that the two strings should differ at exactly one position

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Python modules for fuzzy string comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a more well-performing solution, coded in Python 3:

```
def match(s1, s2):
    ok = False

    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 != c2:
            if ok:
                return False
            else:
                ok = True

    return ok
```

I do not checked for length difference because you said the two strings are equal, but for a more general approach I would add it.

If you need the position of the different character:

```
def match(s1, s2):
    pos = -1

    for i, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
        if c1 != c2:
            if pos != -1:
                return -1
            else:
                pos = i

    return pos
```

These are benchmarks performed with timeit, tested with match("0-001", "0-101"). I translated all solutions to py3 and removed length test.

1. your solution: 5.12
2. Martijn Pieters' solution: 4.92
3. enrico.bacis' and lakesh's solution: 5.51
4. my solution: 2.42

Tests with a longer string:

Martijn Pieters' solution:

```
timeit.timeit('match("0-0016ub5j2oi06u30tj30g6790v3nug[hoyj39867i6gy9thvb05y4b896y3n098vty98thn98qg5y4n8ygnqp", "0-0016ub5j2oi06u30tj30g6790v3gug[hoyj39867i6gy9thvb05y4b896y3n098vty98thn98qg5y4n8ygnqp")', setup="""
def match(s1, s2):
    combo = zip(s1, s2)
    return any(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in combo) and all(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in combo)
""")
```

result: 32.82

My solution:

```
timeit.timeit('match("0-0016ub5j2oi06u30tj30g6790v3nug[hoyj39867i6gy9thvb05y4b896y3n098vty98thn98qg5y4n8ygnqp", "0-0016ub5j2oi06u30tj30g6790v3gug[hoyj39867i6gy9thvb05y4b896y3n098vty98thn98qg5y4n8ygnqp")', setup="""
def match(s1, s2):
    ok = False

    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 != c2:
            if ok:
                return False
            else:
                ok = True

    return ok
""")
```

Result: 20.21

Comment: Instead of setting `ok` to False and breaking, you can just `return False` at that point.

Comment: Can you update this with benchmarks including all test inputs and also *longer* strings?

Comment: @lucas its a very efficient way.Is there a way ,your function can be modified to give position(index) of difference also.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DeepakSaini: you can do: `pos=-1; for i, cc in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)): if cc[0] != cc[1]: if pos != -1: return -1; else: pos =i` and `return pos`. You don't need to return also `True` or `False` if you need the position, because `-1` means there's no match.

Comment: @lucas  thanks a lot.I have been stuck into the problem for quite sometime

Answer (score 12):

I used the Levenshtein distance to match strings that are different by one character added or removed only (and not simply replaced). So:

- John's dog
- Johns dog

are considered as a match.

The Levenshtein distance is the number of edits it would take to replace one string by another. The Levenshtein distance of the two above strings is 1, because the only thing to do is to remove one character.

To use it, you can simply install the according Levenshtein python module:

```
pip install levenshtein
```

and then use it:

```
from Levenshtein import distance 
def match(s1, s2):
    return distance(s1, s2) <= 1
```

Comment: The readme of that package has a warning saying that it's been renamed to simply `levenshtein`. The code is still the same.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2, use [`future_builtins.zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip) (Python 2 and 3 compatible [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)-as-iterator) (in Python 3 the built-in will do fine) to combine the two strings character by character, then use `any()` and `all()` to loop over the resulting iterator:

```
try:
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    pass

def match(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    combo = zip(s1, s2)
    return any(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in combo) and all(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in combo)
```

This works because `combo` is an *iterator*; it yields pairs of characters one by one on demand, and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) only take as many pairs as needed to determine their outcome.

`any()` stops iterating as soon as it finds two characters that are *not* equal. `all()` will only return True if all the *remaining* characters are equal.

Together the two conditions then are *only* True if there is *exactly one pair* that differs.

Because an iterator approach is used, the above does the absolute minimum amount of work to determine if your strings are a match; the moment a second pair is found that doesn't match iteration stops; there is no point in looking at the rest of the character combinations.

Demo (Python 2, so `zip()` is imported):

```
>>> from future_builtins import zip
>>> def match(s1, s2):
...     if len(s1) != len(s2):
...         return False
...     combo = zip(s1, s2)
...     return any(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in combo) and all(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in combo)
... 
>>> match('0011', '0111')
True
>>> match('0-001', '0-101')
True
>>> match('0-011', '0-101')
False
```

Comment: @ Matrtijn Pieters thanks.But iam getting an error that there is no module named future_builtins

Comment: @DeepakSaini: What version of Python is this? You can also use `from itertools import izip as zip`.

Comment: i am using python 3.3.2

Comment: @DeepakSaini: right, then `zip()` is already the 'future builtin'; adjusted to ignore the import error in that case.

Comment: i dont get it.i can see that the method you have given will do my work .But i am not able to import the library.

Comment: @DeepakSaini: The library is *only for Python 2*. You can ignore it in Python 3. You didn't state a version, so I built my answer for both.

Comment: Very cool use of zip as an iterator. However, it looks like it will return false in the event that the strings are equal -- the any expression will return false and so the whole logical expression returns false.

Comment: @Dunes: In that case it *should* return False, as in that case the strings do *not* differ by 1 character.

Comment: That's what I meant. `False and blah` is `False`. Thus, `match("1", "1")` returns false, and I would expect it to return true. Just seen that you've explicitly stated that that is the case. Just that it doesn't completely answer the given question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dunes: Nowhere in the question is it stated that True should be returned if the strings do not differ at all.

Comment: That was my interpretation of the title when it said "allowing one", ie. permitting at most one. But the rest of the question favours your interpretation. I've realised that converting `any(...) and all(...)` to `any(...) or all(...)` would answer my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Dunes: right; in that case you'd get True for **at most** 1 difference indeed.

Answer (score 3):

```
def match(a,b):
    s = sum([a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a))])
    if s == 1:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: Or you could `return s<2`

Answer (score 1):

### Same Lengths

If the two string have the same length:

```
def match(s1, s2):
    return sum(s1[i] != s2[i] for i in xrange(len(s1))) <= 1
```

You can also create a generator of matchers like this:

```
def create_matcher(maxdiff):
    return lambda s1, s2: sum(s1[i] != s2[i] for i in xrange(len(s1))) <= maxdiff

match = create_matcher(1)
```

Example:

```
print match('0011', '0111')      # True
print match('0-001', '0-101')    # True
print match('0-011', '0-101')    # False
```

---

### Different Lengths

If they have different length we can assume that the exceeding characters are different, so:

```
def match(s1, s2):
    l = min(len(s1), len(s2))
    return sum(s1[i] != s2[i] for i in xrange(l)) + abs(len(s1) - len(s2)) <= 1
```