# Levenshtein edit distance algorithm that supports Transposition of two adjacent letters in C#

Tags: c#, nlp, edit-distance

i'm searching for an algorithm for computing Levenshtein edit distance that also supports the case in which two adjacent letters are transposed that is implemented in C#.

for example the word "animals"  and  "ainmals" :
switching between the letters "n" and "i" 
wont be scored as two replacements -which will make a big distance -
but instead on will be scored as a transpose of two letters -much more less distance-

what i reached so far in searching

- [computing Lichtenstein distance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)  but it doesn't contain replacements
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878114/is-there-an-edit-distance-algorithm-that-takes-chunk-transposition-into-accoun)

Comment: I have heard that `transposition` in this case can also be done using a recursive relation, but I am not able to do so. I hope I will be able to deduce it or someone will. The performance in recursive case is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the additional condition to make it a "Damerau–Levenshtein distance" algorithm. So, using the example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein you just need to add the following condition right after step 6:

```
 //** Step 7 to make it Damerau–Levenshtein distance
      if (i > 1 && j > 1 && (s[i - 1] == t[j - 2]) && (s[i - 2] == t[j - 1]))
      {
             d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                            d[i, j],
                            d[i - 2, j - 2] + cost   // transposition
                         );
      }
```

Answer (score 6):

See the implementation on Wikipedia. You can easily adapt the algorithm to include the case for letter swaps. For example:

```
//bla bla. I'm just copying the code on the Wikipedia.
 d[i, j] := minimum
                   (
                     d[i-1, j] + 1,  // a deletion
                     d[i, j-1] + 1,  // an insertion
                     d[i-1, j-1] + 1, // a substitution
                   )

// This single statement is all you need:
if(s[i-1]==t[j-2] && s[i-2]==t[j-1])
   d[i,j] := minimum
                  (
                      d[i,j],               //cost without swapping 
                      d[i-2,j-2]+something  //cost with swapping. probably something=1 
                  );
```