# Fuzzy Matching with threshold filter C#

Tags: c#, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I need to implement some kind of this:

```
string textToSearch = "Extreme Golf: The Showdown";
string textToSearchFor = "Golf Extreme Showdown";
int fuzzyMatchScoreThreshold = 80; // One a 0 to 100 scale
bool searchSuccessful = IsFuzzyMatch(textToSearch, textToSearchFor, fuzzyMatchScoreThreshold);
if (searchSuccessful == true)
{
    -- we have a match.
}
```

Here's the function stub written in C#:

```
public bool IsFuzzyMatch (string textToSearch, string textToSearchFor, int fuzzyMatchScoreThreshold)
{
   bool isMatch = false;
   // do fuzzy logic here and set isMatch to true if successful match.
   return isMatch;
}
```

But I have no any idea how to implement logic in IsFuzzyMatch method.
Any ideas? Perhaps there is a ready-made solution for this purpose?

Comment: You could calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), using words as symbols instead of characters, where words are considered equal based on their Levenshtein distance. There are [many SO topics](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+Levenshtein+distance) on the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451884/similar-string-algorithm/451910#451910

Answer (score 9):

I like a combination of Dice Coeffiecient, Levenshtein Distance, Longest Common Subsequence, and at times the Double Metaphone. The first three will provide you a threshold value. I prefer to combine them in some way. YMMV.

I've just posted a blog post that has a C# implementation for each of these called [Four Functions for Finding Fuzzy String Matches in C# Extensions](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2011/05/27/Four+Functions+For+Finding+Fuzzy+String+Matches+In+C+Extensions.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for find how to go from one string to another by operations insert, delete and modify. You fuzzyMatchScoreThreshold is a Levenshtein Distance divided to length of the string in simple way.