# Algorithm for measuring distance between disordered sequences

Tags: algorithm

The Levenshtein distance gives us a way to calculate the distance between two similar strings in terms of disordered individual characters:

```
quick brown fox
quikc brown fax
```

The Levenshtein distance = 3.

What is a similar algorithm for the distance between two strings with similar subsequences?
For example, in

```
quickbrownfox
brownquickfox
```

the Levenshtein distance is 10, but this takes no account of the fact that the strings have two similar subsequences, which makes them more "similar" than completely disordered words like

```
quickbrownfox
qburiocwknfox
```

and yet this completely disordered version has a Levenshtein distance of eight.

What distance measures exist which take the length of subsequences into account, without assuming that the subsequences can be easily broken into distinct words?

Comment: How is this off-topic? Maybe one could just improve the title.

Comment: Was asked many times under better name :o) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451884/similar-string-algorithm or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246961/algorithm-to-find-similar-text Btw: I especially like the idea with compression based distance.

Comment: @Dario: What title would you suggest?

Comment: @MaR: those questions are not the same as this question. The point is that there is no obvious way to break the string into words.

Comment: Also interesting page comparing different string similarity metrics: http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html Best seems to be SmithWatermanGotoh metric in this comparison.

Comment: @Kinopiko: E.g. something with "measuring distance" in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can try [shingles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling) or some combinations of them with Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 1):

One simple metric would be to take all n*(n-1)/2 substrings in each string, and see how many overlap. There are some simple variations to this approach where you only look at substrings up to a certain length.

This would be similar to the [BLEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU) score commonly used to evaluate machine translations. In the case of BLEU, they are comparing two sentences: they take all the unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, and 4-grams of words from each sentence. They calculate a version of precision and recall for each, and essentially use an average of those scores.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, but the answer is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Initial stab: use a [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) algorithm and the count of the number of differences as your distance

Answer (score 0):

I have an impression that it's NP-complete problem.

At least, I cannot see how can we avoid an exhaustive search. Moreover, I cannot even see how can we verify given solution in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

well the problem you're referring to falls under context sensitive grammar.
You basically define a grammar, the english grammar in this case and then find the distance between a grammar and a mismatch. You'll need to parse your input first.

Comment: It's not the English grammar. These are not English words.