# Resources on generating equivalent phrases (same language translation)?

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp

I'm interested in building a program that takes some text (an article, for example) and then generates a new text with equivalent meaning, but I'm not sure how to get started on such a problem.

Can anyone recommend some code/books/papers/techniques that would help me tackle this?

Comment: Should the meaning be expressed in another language? If not, you're dealing with automatic paraphrasing.

Comment: The meaning does not need to be expressed in another language.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332/whats-a-good-natural-language-library-to-use-for-paraphrasing

Comment: Do you want to summarize the original text or just make minor modifications to each sentence of the original text (e.g. active -> passive, etc.)?

Comment: Hey, Emre, I'm mostly focused on building a program that makes modifications to each sentence, but summarizing a text also sounds useful.

Comment: But summarizing and paraphrasing are totally different as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this one:

- [fastsubs](http://code.google.com/p/fastsubs/): a program to generate most likely substitutes for words in a given text based on an n-gram language model.

More info is available at:

- http://denizyuret.blogspot.be/2012/05/fastsubs-efficient-admissible-algorithm.html